# CRON job not executing php -f

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I'm trying to have a PHP script run once daily (at midnight, server time) in order to update a few files on my website with new data. Here is my cPanel:

[image]

I followed the exact perimeters specified in the example (0 0 * * * - will rune scripts every midnight), and I have the correct file path. Am I using `php -f` correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the php isn't running and failing?

Comment: What happens if you try and run that script on the command line while redirecting all stdin, stdout and stderr to /dev/null?

Comment: Check if normal `php -f /home/...` works. You may change `php` to `/bin/php` or something like that (the real path of `php`). Finally, check file permissions for the user executing the cronjob.

Comment: +1 @fedorqui You can tell where php is by running `which php`

Comment: This is a web hosting service, so I do not have directory access. I'm sure the php script works, as I can visit it manually to achieve it's result.

Comment: See @Farkie's answer below (or @fedorui above). What is also very helpful is setting an email address for success/failures. I believe you can do this in the main cron setup, that will tell you exactly what failed, which will probably be a `php: command not found` error.

Comment: "This is a web hosting service, SO I DO NOT HAVE DIRECTORY ACCESS." Nor command line access for that matter.

Comment: Anyway, you could try a `exec('which php');` to get this.

Answer (score 1):

Try /usr/bin/php (or wherever php binary is installed)